# How to set css border for each line?

Tags: jquery

How can I close the border tag? I mean that each line will have a separate border. Right now when I double click submit, I get both results in the same border

```js
    if (data.status.match("Active")) {
      $(".aprovadas").css("border", "2px solid lightblue");
      $(".aprovadas").css("color", "black");
      $(".aprovadas").css("<br><br>");
      $(".aprovadas").append("Username:" + data.username + "\npassword:" +
        data.password + "\nstatus:" + data.status);
      $(".aprovadas").css("</div>");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You can't append a closing tag and you certainly don't use `css()` method to insert html. You can't think of DOM manipulation as html written in a code editor

Comment: So what do you mean? That there is no way to do it?

Comment: Sure you can do what you want but the DOM only accepts whole elements. Trying to insert a closing tag to break an existing element  into 2 elements is never going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to wrap each line into a div and setup the css rule for that.

```
$(".aprovadas").append("<div style='border-bottom:2px solid lightblue'>Username:" + data.username + "\npassword:" + data.password + "\nstatus:" + data.status + "</div>");
```

Comment: Yes its perfect thank you very much! It also saved me the 3 lines of css